# Pandas Crosstab fill in all values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to fill in all values in Pandas crosstab. My code for creating cross tab look like this:

```
df10 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Rating' : ['A', 'B'],
    'Shop' : ['Shop A', 'Shop B']
})
contigency= pd.crosstab(df10['Rating'], df10['Shop'], values=[1, 2], aggfunc="sum", margins=True)
contigency
```

The result of this code is a cross tab like below:

[image]

My question is, how to **fill in** the NaN with actual values?

The `values` parameter to crosstab function acceppts only the 2 values (same as number of rows), and not 4.

Comment: What actual values? They are `NaN` because they do not appear in your data.

Comment: That's what I want to actually fill in - I am able to add [1, 2] as values but I want to, let's say add [[1, 2], [3, 4]] as values to crosstab.

Comment: That datesn't sound like `crosstab`, it's more `pd.DataFrame( [[1, 2], [3, 4]], index=df10.Rating, columns=df10.Shop)`.